# Como carregar scripts externos

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteorjs

Estou adaptando um tema (Bootstrap) com MeteorJS porém o tema possui mais de 15 *plugins* (jQuery), não posso simplesmente colocá-los na pasta `/client` e carregar todos ao mesmo tempo, tentei algumas coisas (algumas no desespero):

1. Colocar os scripts no rodapé do template com a *tag* `<script>`, porém não foram carregados ou quando o template da um *reload*, se perdem ou não carregam
2. Usando https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/external-file-loader o carregamento é assíncrono, neste caso não viável, estou carregando libraries dependentes entre si.
3. Usando https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/wait-on-lib tenho o mesmo problema do item 2, até consegui fazer eles dependerem um do outro usando callbacks porém é tão horrendo que me recusei a postar o código.

---

EDIT

Ao carregar pela primeira vez a aplicação diversos "Undefined is not a function" vão para o `console`, porém quando o meteor faz o reload, funciona perfeitamente pois a `library` já foi carregada. Utilizei também o `mrt:preloader` porém não surtiu efeito.

O que preciso é carregar uma lista de scripts em ordem síncrona.

Comment: Esses plugins são todos grandes? Não dá para colocar alguns no mesmo ficheiro? Existe um do qual todos dependam? Assim podia ter o jQuery na head e o resto no fundo do body (async)

Comment: Alguns são, porém o problema é que o último script que configura o funcionamento padrão depende de vários scripts anteriores, aí surge o problema: se por exemplo o main.js for carregando antes do jquery-ui.js terei um problema.

Comment: Considere usar o [**require.js**](http://requirejs.org/), que faz carregamento assíncrono com tratamento de dependências.

Comment: @bfavaretto Tentarei utilizar e dou algum retorno.

Comment: @bfavaretto Mesmo utilizando o requirejs não funcionou a questão do load, o problema está assim: Na primeira vez que a página é carregada, qualquer plugin retorna "Undefined is not a function" no reload, como o plugin já foi carregado, funciona normalmente.

Comment: @bfavaretto Realmente o requirejs resolveu o problema! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom imagino que você não quer coisas complicadas, sabendo disso a melhor forma seria em PRODUÇÃO colocar tudo isso de forma sequencial em um único arquivo e compressa-lo com esta ferramenta do Google

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

É a melhor forma de se obter desempenho

Comment: O problema está em carregá-los de modo síncrono e em ordem.

Comment: JavaScript é uma linguagem que dá prioridade para sincronia e todos os navegadores sabem disso por esse motivo eles sabem bem como processá-lo da melhor forma mesmo que síncrona, o importante é fazer um cacheamento bem feito dos mesmos na minha opinião

Answer (score 0):

O jeito que o Meteor carrega os arquivos é uma dor de cabeça. Porém, existem alguns diretórios com significados especiais:

```
client/compatibility -- Todos as bibliotecas que esperam ser globais, são carregadas primeiro
```

Um modo de ajustar isso com as dependências, é dentro da pasta `client/compatibility` nomear os arquivos em order numérica. O Meteor carrega os arquivos por ordem lexicográfica.

Isso seria horrendo e difícil de fazer, além de sujeito a erros caso a lib mude as dependências (iria envolver você ter que mudar o nome dos arquivos). Então, o modo que recomendo é criar `packages`.

O sistema de pacotes do Meteor deixa você especificar de modo explícito as dependências entre os arquivos .js.

Link: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs

Um jeito seria criar um pacote para cada plugin. Mapear as dependências entre eles e integrá-los usando o sistema de pacotes do Meteor.
Quando feito `meteor deploy` ou `meteor build`, os pacotes serão minificados em um só JS com a aplicação.

Outra ideia poderia ser mapear as dependências mais acopladas e fazer delas um único pacote. Fica a seu critério, na verdade.